# Android "Manage Applications" shows my app name as my package name instead of a friendly name

Tags: android

Manage applications shows my app as "com.mydomain.myapp" instead of "My App".  What do I need to change?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's my problem.  In the manifest, this was at the activity level instead of the app level.
android:label="@string/app_name">

Answer (score 1):

I also just had this problem.

As you said, must include  android:label="@string/app_name" at < application level. I also performed a "Clean Project". These two things fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem

I think this happens because build project does not affect the manifest file change on the go

first I clean the project and then restarted the emulator

after that project installed with my nice app name.